# Deploying Spring Application on Tomcat 8.5.9 returns 404 1034 error in localhost access log

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

New poster here so I'll dive right in. Sorry if I miss any important information, let me know and I'll update you.

My problem is that when I go to my application: localhost:8080/GettingStartedSpringMVC/ - I get a 404 error on the screen and a 404 1034 error on the logs but that is it, no other useful information in any log I can find.

I am creating a basic Spring MVC Web application in Java. I am following the "Spring in Action" vol. 4. I have identical code including the test case, which returns success. When I go to "Export > WAR file" and put it into my local Apache instance the WAR file successfully explodes. I am able to access localhost:8080, localhost:8080/test/index.html, and even localhost:8080/GettingStartedSpringMVC/helloworld.html which are .html files I created to make sure deployment was going normally - the last one is inside the project that I cannot access. I have the logs in my apache tomcat instance but there doesn't appear to be anything useful in them - unless I don't know where to look.

If I could find an error, I would be happy to look into it but I can't manage to find anything. Not sure how to post files either - just copy/paste? If anything is needed, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error in one of the files that meant it did not scan for all the components. Also, was not able to confirm but there potentially may have been an issue with the WAR bringing necessary JAR files. I placed them in the lib file instead of relying on the Eclipse linking.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Catalina.out and other server logs inside logs  folder?

Also, double check if your static files are not in web-inf which is not accessible.

In addition, check that javac is on the path of you are using JSP

Comment: There is no catalina.out log in the /logs directory. There is a catalina.<date> file that contains server stop, start, and deployment details but I can't see anything of interest relating to my issue.

My jsp is /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp, why would this be not accessible?

How would you recommend checking that javac is on the JSP path? I have checked to make sure that JAVA_HOME is configured for apache correctly.